Changing label counter from 7 to 1 in an appendix
I am trying to change the label counter in my appendix from 7 to 1, so I can refefence to the first Appendix. As I have used enumerate multiple times earlier in the report, this is the 7'th list. I decided to use enumerate list for my appendix as I found this to be the easiest.
Is there an easy way to change my label counter for this list?
\chapter*{A - Guideline questions}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}A - Guideline 
questions} 

\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\textwidth,colback={Apricot},title= 
{\textbf{Guideline questions in Norwegian followed by English 
translation in cursive}},colbacktitle=Peach,coltitle=black]

\begin{enumerate}
     \item[$\bullet$]Kan du gi innsikt i den nåværende tilstanden til solenergiindustrien i Norge?
    \\  \textit{Can you provide insights into the current state of the solar energy industry in Norway?}
    
     \item[$\bullet$]Hvordan påvirker geopolitiske forhold, som internasjonale konflikter eller handelsdynamikk, solenergikjeden i Norge?
    \\ \textit{How do geopolitical factors, such as international conflicts or trade dynamics, impact the solar energy chain in Norway?}
    
     \item[$\bullet$]Hvor stor markedsinteresse mener du det er for norsk/europeisk-produserte sol(celler/komponenter)?
    \\ \textit{How significant do you believe the market interest is for Norwegian/European-manufactured solar (cells/components)?}
    
     \item[$\bullet$]Hva kan gjøre norsk produsenter/leverandører konkurransedyktige?
    \\ \textit{What factors could make Norwegian producers/suppliers competitive?}
    
     \item[$\bullet$]Har du noen formeninger om tiltak eller strategier du mener vil styrke deres og lignende bedrifters mulighet for å utnytte deres fulle potensial i Norge?
    \\ \textit{Do you have any opinions on measures or strategies that you believe would strengthen your and similar companies' ability to enhance their potential in Norway?}
    
     \item[$\bullet$]Har du noen innsikt i statens/regjeringens vilje til å støtte solverdikjeden i Norge?
    \\ \textit{Do you have any insights into the government's willingness to support the solar value chain in Norway?}
    
     \item[$\bullet$]Hvordan kan samarbeid mellom bransjeaktører styrke solenergiindustrien i Norge og Europa?
    \\ \textit{How can collaboration among industry stakeholders strengthen the solar energy industry in Norway and Europe?}
\end{enumerate}
\label{Guideline_questions}
\end{tcolorbox}


Welcome! I see nothing in the code that generates a number, and \label refers to the last generated number. It probably refers to the last section's number, like all the other similar lists you have, so the referenced numbera are “right” by chance.

Why are you using an enumerate environment instead of an itemize environment? This would let you change all instances of \item[$\bullet$] to just \item .

@egreg Hmm okey, any ideas on how to reset the counter/label?

@Mico I don't have an answer to that. Itemize works fine as well, I was just experimenting.

What label are you trying to reset?  \label{Guideline_questions} doesn't refer to anything you've shown (if I add 5 lines to complete your example, \ref is blank).  What are you wanting the label to refer to?

@Hansy Sorry, but a \label in that position is only reliable for the page number (although, for that purpose, it should be just at the beginning of the environment).

Can you tell us why you want to use a label here? Usually, people use a label so they can refer to something later e.g. see chapter 4 or as shown in derivation 3.2 or whatever. But that's only useful if there is a chapter 4 or a derivation 3.2 marked as such for the reader to find. There's no point telling somebody to 'see chapter 4' if your chapters don't have numbers.

The code I presented represents Appendix A in my report, I want to reference to this. Therefore I though adding a label would solve this. My Appendix does not have a chapter/section @cfr
As i now reference in the text;
"The conducted interviews were based of the guideline questions seen in appendix \ref{Guideline_questions}"
I get: "The conducted interviews were based of the guideline questions seen in appendix 7". And I would prefer to reference directly to "Appendix A" or "Appendix 1".

Currently, the appendix is unnumbered. \chapter* means it doesn't get a number. So the 7 is nothing to do with the appendix. The \label cannot pick up the A because you are hard-coding it rather than having LaTeX number it with a counter. So probably what you want to do is to reset the counter and change the format. However, if you are using hyperref, you may have trouble if you're reusing numbers. If you provide code for a proper minimal example people can compile, it would be easier to help. This stuff is very class/package dependant.

@cfr I figured out a method using link. I ended up referencing to the \section*{Appendix} using \label{a} in the unnumbered section and \hyperref[{a}]{A} where I wanted the referring to take place. I did not achieve what I originally wanted, but at least i refer to the right page now. Thanks a lot for the advice!

@Hansy Why don't you just use code which numbers appendices with letters in the first place?
